# API Management on IBM Cloud for Node.js vs CORS headers

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have an Node.JS application that defines CORS settings. We thought about taking advantage of limitting requests per client-id that comes with 'API Management'. This 'API Management' has it's own CORS enable toggle. But even when 'Off', it seems to overwrite application CORS headers.

Did some experimenting with app like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.get('/hasset', cors({ origin: "http://localhost/" }), function(req, res) {
    return res.json({status: "ok", message: "with cors setting"});
});
app.get('/nonset', function(req, res){ 
    return res.json({"status":"ok", "message":"without cors"});
});

var port = (process.env.PORT || 3100);
app.listen(port);
console.log('App started on port ' + port);
```

Should we wan't to use own CORS settings - does that rule us out of 'API Management' ?

Comment: Can you tell us which service you are using? Are you using the API Connect service on IBM Cloud?

Comment: Like i said: I have "Node.JS" application (runtime) on IBM Cloud, that - in console - has 'API Management' on left navigation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. IBM Cloud used to have an API Management service so I wanted to be sure that you were not using a legacy service instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use API Management and simply turn off the "CORS" option. In that case, the gateway will simply pass through any CORS headers you return manually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that option wasn't there when I tried it - but good to know it's now there - certainly useful.